# Swift: How to make a custom view update elements to its size

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a custom view using the `CVCalendar` pod (https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar) that lays out dates within a UIView (calendarView). This works as expected when the view is loaded either in portrait or landscape but when the view transitions to landscape on an IPad the dates no longer fit the view properly, cutting off the last row of dates for the month due to being unable to simultaneously satisfy layout constraints. I have not set a height for the calendarView the following seems to be set upon rotation:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint: CVCalendar.CVCalendarView:.height == 683.333   (active)>"
```

That constraint is then broken:

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 

<NSLayoutConstraint: CVCalendar.CVCalendarView:.height == 683.333   (active)>
```

My current view is set up within a tab bar item and is as follows:

- label 1 (orange in image) at the top of the view provides the month and year with a set height of 40 and 0 points to superview.
- menuView (black in image)of the calendar displaying the days of the week with a set height of 40. 0 points from label 1 and calendarView.
- calendarView (white in image)containing dates of the month. No set height. 8 points to Label 2.
- label 2, 3 & 4 (green,blue & purple in image)are displaying information and are set to a height of 30, with equal heights. Label 4 is 0 points from the superview.

[image: view layout]

Comment: Does the bottom row of dates *no longer fit* in your calendar view? Or, is the bottom of your calendar being *covered by* the orange label?

Comment: I have checked the thoroughly and it 100% does not fit the view rather than being covered.

Comment: To add to this, if the calendar view is loaded in landscape mode it fits the view fine, but then when rotated to portrait and back to landscape it no longer fits as above.

Comment: OK  - I grabbed CVCalendar and created a simple sample app, and have no problem when rotating the device / changing the size of the calendar view:  https://imgur.com/a/quqTF.  I suggest commenting out some of any "customizing" code you are using. If / when you get to a point where the row is no longer missing, then add back in your customization one piece at a time.

Comment: By the way... are you getting any *"Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints."* warning / error messages?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. you were correct that it is a constraints issue but I have been trying to solve it and have had no success. I have updated the question to reflect the layout problems and would be grateful if you could have a quick look. Thanks!

Comment: I mucked around a bit, and it seems this control has a few issues - orientation when the calendar height also changes among them. Give this a try though: in `CVCalendarView.swift` line 282 should be `if selfSize.height > maxHeight {` ... remove that `if` condition, and instead ***always*** set `maxHeight = selfSize.height`. See if that helps.